# Coverflow design in android

Tags: android

I have been trying to use the Coverflow feature for my application ,Can any one suggest a good link or a sample code to learn to design a Coverflow in android , i searched a lot , but dint find a good one .

Comment: check out-
http://androidsnips.blogspot.in/2011/03/images-with-coverflow-like-animation-in.html

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good one. You'll can modify it to suit your needs:

https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice video which may help you-

http://youtu.be/V67cMYjvzo8

To access the coverflow view just use: Coverflow coverflow = (Coverflow)findViewById(R.id.cover_flow)

The XML Layout-

Create a LinearLayout with the orientation set to vertical and set that as your content view. Then add the Cover flow view and the list view to the layout.

If you do it in a layout xml it would be something like this (change the "com.example.package" to the pckage where your CoverFlow is located):

```
<com.example.package.CoverFlow
    android:id="@+id/cover_flow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```